# Angular - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<User, "email">'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to call the login service from frontend but it return the following error when I try to pass the value from form control to the login function in service:

```
Error: src/app/login/login.component.ts:22:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<User, "email">'.

22     this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe();
```

Here is the code:

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService
    ){ }

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7)])
  });

  login():void{
    this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe();
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { first, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { ErrorhandleService } from './errorhandle.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private url = "http://localhost:4242/auth";
  isUserLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  uid!: Pick<User, 'uid'>;


  httpOptions:{
    headers: HttpHeaders
  }={
    headers: new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json"})
  }

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private errorHandlerService: ErrorhandleService,
    private router: Router) { }

  signup(user: Omit<User, "uid">): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.url}/signup`, user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      first(),
      catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError<User>('signup'))
    )
  }

  login(email: Pick<User, "email">, password: Pick<User, 'password'>): Observable<{ token: string; uid: Pick<User, "uid">; }> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/login`, { email, password }, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      first(),
      tap(
        (tokenObject:any)=>{
          this.uid=tokenObject.uid;
          localStorage.setItem('token', tokenObject.token);
          this.isUserLoggedIn$.next(true);
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
      ),
      catchError(
        this.errorHandlerService.handleError<{
          token: string;
          uid: Pick<User, "uid">;
        }>("login")
      )
    )
  }
}
```

**user.ts**

```
export interface User{
    uid: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
    company: string;
}
```

Tried keyof, but it still return same error. And I have no idea where the error come from.

Comment: You can find out more about `Pick` here: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-typescript-pick-mapped-type

Answer (score 2):

`Pick<User, 'email'>` will construct type `{email: string}`

you are probably looking for `User['email']` type, which would be equal `string` in this case